# Rails 4 - has_many through, splitting into 2 types using conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many, rails-models

I have a working has_many through relationship between 2 models with a joining model.

```
Company, Film, CompanyFilm
```

Many films have many companies. Nice and easy, but what I want to do is define the "type" of relationship on the joining model, using conditions.

CompanyFilm has an additional field called "role" that can be either "financier" or "publisher".

This is my current setup: (class Film)

```
has_many :financier_companies, -> { where(company_films: {role: 'financier'}) }, :class_name => "CompanyFilm"
has_many :financiers, :through => :financier_companies, :source => :company

has_many :publisher_companies, -> { where(company_films: {role: 'publisher'}) }, :class_name => "CompanyFilm"
has_many :publishers, :through => :publisher_companies, :source => :company
```

And my form:

```
<%= f.label :financier_company_ids, "Developers" %><br />
<%= f.select :financier_company_ids, Company.all.collect {|financier| [financier.name, financier.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

On saving, I get this error:

```
Couldn't find CompanyFilm with 'id'=2
```

Any ideas?
Also is it best practice to have 1 field as a string to define the relationship, or better to have multiple boolean fields like "financier?" and "publisher?". In my example, it is possible for a company to be both. Many thanks!

Comment: why are you using `Company.all` i suppose it should be `Company.where(company_films: {role: 'financier'})` ? show more details from your controller, so we can track the bug source.

Comment: Ah yes, I should specify - I want users to be able to select any Company, but there's 2 different select input fields - one for financiers and another for publishers. In both, any Company can be selected but it should define the "role" of the relationship.

Comment: As for the controller, it's all pretty much default - although I have added "financier_company_ids" to the film_params in films_controller.rb.

Comment: <%= f.collection_select : financier_company_ids, Company.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } %> is cleaner but this does't solve your issue.

Comment: @Kobius "In my example, it is possible for a company to be both" - if you mean that a company can be a financier and a publisher, then a single role field will not work. Why not create a `Role` model with `CompanyFilm` has_many `Roles`?

Comment: Why do you have 2 sets of `has_many :through` statements in your Film model? You should do one generic `has_many :through` and then use [scopes]( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to distinguish between the two. Also @Anand makes a good point: unless you want to have multiple CompanyFilm instances with the same Company and Film, but different roles, you need to rethink what you want to store in that field, if not break it out into a new table of roles.

Comment: Your associations are not correct. Do `has_many :company_films` and then use it with `:through` for each of the other associations and use class 'Company' instead of 'CompanyFilm'.